# Difference between "#someid ul li.someclass a" and "#someid ul li .someclass a" ? (notice the whitespace)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I dont have much experiences in CSS, but recently i found out that there is a difference between having a whitespace before a class selector and without having one. So far, I only know that they are interpreted as two different things...Can somebody experienced in CSS explains to me what the particular difference is? Does this also apply to id selector?

Thanks. appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`#someid ul li.someclass a` means

> Anchors that are descendants of
>   **list items that have the class `someclass`** and are themselves descendants of
>   unordered lists that are descendants of
>   the element with ID `someid`.

`#someid ul li .someclass a` means

> Anchors that are descendants of
>   **any elements that have the class `someclass`** and are themselves descendants of
>   list items that are descendants of
>   unordered lists that are descendants of
>   the element with ID `someid`.

So, the `<a>` element in the following markup is matched by the first rule, but not by the second:

```
<div id="someid">
    <ul>
        <li class="someclass">
            <a href="foo.html" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the `<a>` element in the following markup is matched by the second rule, but not by the first:

```
<div id="someid">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="someclass">
                <a href="foo.html" />
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 Hopefully, my edit makes things clearer. The paragraphs were rather hard to read ;)

Comment: @BoltClock, that's indeed a lot clearer now (I suppose I shouldn't always aim to keep sentences together, after all, that's *code* we're talking about most of the time here). Nice edit, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Two examples:

`#someid ul li.someclass a` will hit the anchor tag in this example

```
<div id="someid">
  <ul>
    <li class="someclass">
      <a href="http://www.example.com">link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`#someid ul li .someclass a` will hit the anchor tag in this example

```
<div id="someid">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="someclass">
        <a href="http://www.example.com">link</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Also notice that this will hit both of them:

```
<div id="someid">
  <ul>
    <li class="someclass">
      <div class="someclass">
        <a href="http://www.example.com">link</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```